# Prove that $L(\psi_N , s) = \zeta(s) \prod_{p \mid N}(1 − p^{-s})$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $N$ be a positive integer, and let $\psi_N$ be the trivial Dirichlet character with conductor $N,$ so $\psi_N (a) = 0$ if $\gcd(a, N) \ne 1$ and $\psi_N (a) = 1$ if $\gcd(a, N) = 1.$ Prove that $L(\psi_N , s) = \zeta(s) \prod_{p \mid N}(1 − p^{-s})$.

By definition, $L(\chi_d,s) = \displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{\chi_d(n)}{n^s} =  \displaystyle \prod_{p \text{ prime }} \left(1 - \dfrac{\chi_d(p)}{p^s} \right)^{-1}$ and if $\chi_d$ is a trivial character then $\chi_d(a)=1$ for every $a \in (\mathbb{Z}/p \mathbb{Z})^{\ast}.$ Thus $\chi_d(p) = 1$ for every prime. We also have that $\zeta(s) = \displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-s} = \displaystyle \prod_{p \text{ prime }} \left(1- \dfrac{1}{p^{s}} \right)^{-1}.$ I feel like I'm close but can't get the expression to match $\zeta(s) \prod_{p \mid N}(1 − p^{-s}).$

Where do I go from here?

Comment: In the product $$\prod_{p\text{ prime}} \biggl(1 - \frac{\psi_N(p)}{p^s}\biggr)^{-1},$$ you want the numerators equal to $1$ - except when?

Comment: When $p \nmid N$?

Comment: That's when you want the numerator of the fraction in the parenthesis to be $1$.

Comment: so we want the numerator of $\dfrac{\chi_N(p)}{p^s}$ equal to $1$ except when $p \mid N$?

Comment: Yes. And does $\psi_N$ do that?

Comment: I think so, it maps to $0$ when $p \mid N$ and to $1$ when $p \nmid N$ right?

Comment: Indeed. So $$L(\psi_N,s) = \prod_{p\nmid N} \biggl(1-\frac{1}{p^s}\biggr)^{-1}.$$

Comment: How do we show that $L(\psi_N,s) = \displaystyle \prod_{p \nmid N} \left(1 - p^{-s} \right)^{-1} =\displaystyle \prod_{p \text{ prime }} \left(1- p^{-s} \right) \displaystyle \prod_{p \mid N} \left(1- p^{-s} \right)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have the Euler product representation

$$L(\psi_N,s) = \prod_{p\text{ prime}}\biggl(1 - \frac{\psi_N(p)}{p^s}\biggr)^{-1}$$

for $\operatorname{Re} s > 1$, and the product converges absolutely, hence can be reordered and split arbitrarily. Splitting the set of primes into those that divide $N$ and those that don't, we have

$$L(\psi_N,s) = \Biggl(\prod_{p\mid N} \biggl(1 - \frac{\psi_N(p)}{p^s}\biggr)^{-1}\Biggr)\cdot \Biggl(\prod_{p\nmid N} \biggl(1 - \frac{\psi_N(p)}{p^s}\biggr)^{-1}\Biggr).$$

By definition of $\psi_N$, we have $\psi_N(p) = 1$ if $p\nmid N$, and $\psi_N(p) = 0$ if $p\mid N$, so

$$L(\psi_N,s) = \Biggl(\prod_{p\mid N}\biggl(1 - \frac{0}{p^s}\biggr)^{-1}\Biggr)\cdot \Biggl(\prod_{p\nmid N}\biggl( 1 - \frac{1}{p^s}\biggr)^{-1}\Biggr) = \prod_{p\nmid N}\bigl(1 - p^{-s}\bigr)^{-1}.$$

And we have

\begin{align}
\zeta(s) &= \prod_{p \text{ prime}} \bigl(1 - p^{-s}\bigr)^{-1}\\
&= \Biggl(\prod_{p\nmid N} \bigl(1 - p^{-s}\bigr)^{-1}\Biggr)\cdot \Biggl(\prod_{p\mid N}\bigl(1 - p^{-s}\bigr)^{-1}\Biggr)\\
&= L(\psi_N,s)\cdot \prod_{p\mid N}\bigl(1 - p^{-s}\bigr)^{-1}\\
&= \frac{L(\psi_N,s)}{\prod\limits_{p\mid N} (1 - p^{-s})},
\end{align}

from which the desired

$$L(\psi_N,s) = \zeta(s)\cdot \prod_{p\mid N}\bigl(1 - p^{-s}\bigr)$$

follows by multiplication with the denominator of the right hand side.

Comment: Very clear and succinct answer. Thank you